# Grub set default startup to a Ubuntu 16.04 installed at /dev/mapper

Tags: ubuntu, grub, startup, defaults

I have two Ubuntu systems installed, one 14.04 and one 16.04. From the Grub menu I can see that:

```
*Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+)
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (on /dev/sda1)
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root)
```

Every time, the PC will start by the default Ubuntu option, and load the Ubuntu 14.04. I want to change this default start up to Ubuntu 16.04. However, not successful.

Things I tried:

1. change /etc/default/grub

   GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
   GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
   GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root"
   GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm"

Neither GRUB_DEFAULT="saved" or GRUB_DEFAULT="3" is working.

2. Try to change 40_custom of grub.d not working
3. In the grub.cfg file, there is no Ubuntu 16.04 (which is really strange as I can see this option in the Grub and I can manually scroll down and choose to start with Ubuntu 16.04).
4. In the Grub Customizer there is no Ubuntu 16.04, but has Ubuntu 14.04

Please advice what should I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know only for Bios-Installation.
First you need to know which grub is leading (Trust or xenial)

```
sudo hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 "%x" "\n"' /dev/sda
```

Bytecode `48b4` means GRUB 2 (Version 1.96) `7c3c` means  GRUB 2 (Version 1.97 oder 1.98) `020`  means GRUB 2 (Version 1.99)
In /etc/default/grub/

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

Then run    `sudo update-grub`

Then boot xenial and your choice will be remembered. `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`